# Analysis of Alternating Decision Tree on Weka

Tags: algorithm, tree, classification, weka, decision-tree

I am applying the AD Tree algorithm & this is the tree visualization of the output:

[image]

I can't understand the values in the decision nodes (-0.4,0.541,-0.882...), How are these calculated? & how did we calculate the root node's score?

Are predicate conditions (<127.5..) formed by entropy splitting mechanism?

This is an image of the output:

[image]

Any help is appreciated, cannot find any AD Tree output analysis document!!

Answer (score 0):

Let's take that first split:
[image]

The 1: plas indicates this is the first node, and we're splitting on the attribute plas.
If plas is less than 127.5, these instances to to the left.
If plas is 127.5 or more, these instances go to the right.
The overall mean is -0.311 (from the top of the tree).
The mean for cases that went down the left branch is -0.4.
The mean for cases that went down the right branch is +0.541.

Comment: Thank you! Do you know how the mean variables are calculated ??

Comment: Good question about the means. Doing this in my head, it looked like -.311 was the difference between the probability of a negative, 500/768 = .651, and the probability of a positive, 268/768 = .349.  But when I do the actual calculation I see that difference is -.302, and not -.311.  So I'm not quite sure what's being calculated here.